# Create clickable link in text view in android

Tags: android

I have some hash tags in a `TextView` which are starts with '#'

Example:"#one#two Hello World #three".

I wants these hash tags clickable separately and open an activity and getting this text in that activity.

So these hash are working as a link and open up an activity. Also the tags are not fixed means that may be any text. Also change the color of hash tags to red and color of rest of tags will be black

**Example:** [#one](http://a.com)[#two](http://b.com) Hello World [#three](http://c.com)

Comment: does the texts vary dynamically?

Comment: Yes text is not constant

Comment: try the below and also test by changing the positions of #

Comment: did you try does it work or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modify the below according to your requirement. Use a `SpannableString`

```
String s ="#one #Two Hello World #three";
String split[] = s.split("#");
TextView_tv = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.tv );
for(int i=1;i<split.length;i++)
{
  SpannableString ss1=  new SpannableString("#"+split[i]);     
  ss1.setSpan(new  MyClickableSpan(""+i), 0, 1,  Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
  ss1.setSpan(newForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),0,1,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
  _tv.append(ss1);
   _tv.append(" ");   
}
_tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

class MyClickableSpan extends ClickableSpan{    
String clicked;
public MyClickableSpan(String string) {

    super();
    clicked =string;
    }

    public void onClick(View tv) {
        if(clicked.equals("1"))
        {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "One",1000).show();
        }
        else if(clicked.equals("2"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Two",1000).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Three",1000).show();       
        }

   }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
       ds.setUnderlineText(false); // set to false to remove underline
    }
    } 
   }
```

Snap on Emulator

On each hash click displays toast one, two and three. Instead of toast start a new activity.

[image]

Edit:

If you want the string clicked

```
 ss1.setSpan(new  MyClickableSpan(""+i,split[i]), 0, 1,  Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Then

```
 String clicked;
 String astring;
 public MyClickableSpan(String check,String actualstring) {
super();
clicked =check;
astring =actualstring; // pass this to next activity using intent
}
```

Then

```
  public void onClick(View tv) {
        if(clicked.equals("1"))
        {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), astring,1000).show();
        }
        else if(clicked.equals("2"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), astring,1000).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), astring,1000).show();       
        }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LinearLayout` :

- **In xml add :**

  ```
  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/tag_ET"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="4"
      android:gravity="left"
      android:inputType="text" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/add_Btn"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="right"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="@string/tags_add_btn_text" />
  ```

  ```
  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/tags_view"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:orientation="horizontal" />
  ```
- **Init layout :**

  ```
  // EditText to write Tags.
  EditText tag = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tag_ET));
  // Button used to add tags
  Button addTagBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_Btn));
  // layout contains added tags.
  final LinearLayout tagsView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tags_view);
  ```
- **Add tags to tagView :**

  ```
      final String tagTxt = tagEt.getText().toString();
      if (!tagTxt.isEmpty()) {
          Spannable buttonLabel = new SpannableString(tagTxt);

          // clear tag edit text
          tagEt.setText("");

          // add tag to layout
          Button btn = new Button(this);
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
          LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
          lout.addView(btn, tagsView);

          btn.setText(buttonLabel);
          btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hover);
          btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  // Toast whatever you want.
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tagTxt,1000).show();
              }
          });
      }
  ```