# How to change the colour of only one letter in a textview?

Tags: android, colors, textview

I easily have one `TextView` on my app. How does it work to change the color of only one letter in the `TextView`?
Is it possible to adjust it only in the XML?

Comment: You can use a SpannableString for this purpose. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908547/create-clickable-link-in-text-view-in-android. the answer in the link should give you a clue.

Answer (score 1):

use `SpannableString` like:

```
SpannableString redSpannable= new SpannableString("string");
redSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, index, index+1);
```

set `redSpannable` to textview

Comment: Downvote because it should have been flagged as (one of the many) duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+textview+change+color+part

Comment: What means index? Eclipse has the warning "Index cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: @BenPearson you can flag it as duplicate. But he is not copying the content from those posts. That should not be a reason to downvote as the post is not entirely incorrect. duplicate means simply flag the question and close it as duplicate