# Android TextView with multiple click events

Tags: android, textview, spannable, text-styling

In my android app i have to show tags on Textview.
There can be multiple tag in same textView and i want to add click event to each tag.
There may be some other text in same textview.How can i formate text in such a way all tags are clickable with bold text and other text as normal text.
Suppose Text "#tag1 text message #tag2 #tag3 normal text"  is to be set in text view with #tag1,#tag2 and #tag3 with bold text and remaining text with normal text style,so how can i achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908547/create-clickable-link-in-text-view-in-android

Comment: +1 for your answer.Thanks your answer help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this,

```
String str = "<b> #tag1 </b> " + textMessage + "<b> #tag2  #tag3 </b>" + normalText; 
your_textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));
```

You can try [SpannableStringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html) also.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [SpannableStringBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder)

SpannableStringBuilder can:

- Change Text Color
- Multiple Click Actions etc

For code reference, you can check this [post](https://medium.com/viithiisys/android-multiple-click-actions-on-single-textview-c5fec71b6e25)

```
private static void singleTextView(TextView textView, final String userName, String status, final String songName) {

    SpannableStringBuilder spanText = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    spanText.append(userName);
    spanText.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {

            // On Click Action

        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint textPaint) {
            textPaint.setColor(textPaint.linkColor);    // you can use custom color
            textPaint.setUnderlineText(false);    // this remove the underline
        }
    }, spanText.length() - userName.length(), spanText.length(), 0);

    spanText.append(status);
    spanText.append(songName);
    spanText.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {

            // On Click Action

        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint textPaint) {
            textPaint.setColor(textPaint.linkColor);    // you can use custom color
            textPaint.setUnderlineText(false);    // this remove the underline
        }
    },spanText.length() - songName.length(), spanText.length(), 0);

    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    textView.setText(spanText, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

}
```